# Can cron job add some information to cron log?

Tags: macos, python, cron

I am running OSX 10.10.4 and have a cron job scheduled there (it runs python script).
Log file is enabled there in accordance with this answer - https://superuser.com/a/595825/172606. But the log created contains information about cron job starts and crontab file updates only. Is there any way to put some information there from my python script? (don't want to create [separate log](https://superuser.com/a/122255/172606) for each python script I have)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know about OSX but on linux we have the `logger` command to add log entries via syslog:

```
$ logger -p cron.info 'some important message'
```